# Explanation of Cross-Modality Linear Transformer

Tags: transformer

So I am trying to understand how a Cross-Modality Linear Transformer is different from an a basic transformer. I found the transformer mentioned in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.15001.pdf). Am I correct in understanding that, the transformer  is cross-modality because it is going from one medium to another. In this case, text to motion. Then linear because the time complexity to calculate the attetion weights are linear? I have troubles with understanding transformers. I just was able to understand the basic concept of them. So any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self-attention part 'enriches' the motion sequence. The cross-attention module mixes two different embedding sequences. In a language translation model, the cross-attention module is the part where the actual translation happens. In the MotionDiffuse paper, this is the part where the two modalities (motion sequence and text) interact.

[image: minimax game]

The original attention mechanism however does not scale very well. Computing the attention weights leads to quadratically increasing costs. The MotionDiffuse paper makes use of the speed-ups introduced in the

> Efficient Attention paper (Shen et al., 2021). Instead of calculating pair-wise attention weights, efficient attention generates global
> feature map.

See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EixI6t5oif0) for a detailed explanation of the original transformer architecture.

Comment: Thanks, could this model be considered a latent diffusion model? I just finished reading [this](https://theaisummer.com/diffusion-models/#stable-diffusion-latent-diffusion-models) and it seemed to fit the description.